# Passing component to render by "Component" not by "<Component/>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components

Im developing a own "BottomBar" implementation... Therefore I want to pass a Screen to render by its name... The problem here is it only works when I pass the screen as a tag, not as a component.

```
  <BottomBar>
    <BottomTab screen={HomeScreen}>
      <Text>Home</Text>
      <Icon name='home' />
    </BottomTab>
  <BottomTab screen={<HomeScreen/>}>
    <Text>Drill&Game</Text>
    <Icon name='logo-game-controller-a' />
  </BottomTab>
</BottomBar>
```

The Bottombar tries to render the passed screen like this...

```
    render(){           

    // Defining nativebase
    // Passing open screen inside the content
    let nativebase = <Container>
                        <Content>{this.screen(this.state)}</Content>
                        <Footer>
                            <FooterTab>{childs}</FooterTab>
                        </Footer>
                  </Container>;



    // Rendering either one or the other based on the configs.
    return nativebase;
}

/**
 * Returns the fitting screen for the open tab.
 * Once we click on a tab, this gets called as a callback in order to
 * Change the screen... BottomTab contains a array of 
 * @param {} props 
 */
screen = (props) => {

    let openScreen = props.screen;
    return this.state.screens[openScreen];
}
```

HomeScreen is a simple class with a constructor and a render method in order to show the screen correctly... its no function or lambda.

Sooo somehow the screen gets rendered properly when I pass it as a tag... but not when I pass its name... any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: well if you "render" it via `<Container />` that is transpiled to `React.createElement(Container, {})`. If you just pass the *reference* of the component, it'll never be "constructed" / rendered

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks ! And how do I write it correctly that the object gets constructed ?

Comment: Well if you pass the component by reference then you need to "render" it (aka wrap it with brackets so its compiled to createElement). If you pass the "rendered" component then you dont need to do anything except place it in your render. `<BottomTab screen={HomeScreen}>` you would need to render it this way, `const { screen: ScreenComponent } = this.props` and then `<ScreenComponent />`... If you pass the screen already constructed `screen=<HomeScreen />` then you can just render it as is `{ screen }`